# Issue with bootstrap navbar dropdown button active color

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, css

Here is a picture of my navbar. Notice how home is merely underlined when active...
[image]

Here is another picture of my navbar. Unfortunately, the dropdown menu when it is active is highlighted as this color, and none of the css that I have tried has been able to fix it. It should have a transparent background like all of the ones above it. Any help is greatly appreciated. [image]

Here is my html for the navbar...

```html
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top font">
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Title -->
    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
      <div class="navbar-brand-image"> <%=link_to "#{image_tag 'rsz_1rsz_13logo.png'}".html_safe ,root_path %></div>
    </div>

    <button id="nav-icon1" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">

      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>

    </button>


    <!-- Additional navbar items -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navHeaderCollapse">
      <!--                      pull-right keeps the drop-down in line -->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

          <li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(root_path) %>"><% yield (:home)%><%= link_to "Home", root_path%></li>
        <li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(services_path) %>"><% yield (:services)%><%= link_to "Services", services_path%></li>
        <li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(careers_path) %>"><% yield (:careers)%><%= link_to "Careers", careers_path%></li>
          <li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(contact_path) %>"><% yield (:contact)%><%= link_to "Contact Us", contact_path %>
          <li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(about_us_path) %>"><% yield (:about_us)%><%= link_to "About Us", about_us_path%></li>
        <li class="dropdown nav-drop">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Language <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="  background-color: rgba(54,54,54, .6);">
            <li><a href="/">English</a></li>
            <li><a href="/de/home">German</a></li>
            <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Spanish - Coming Soon</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap's `.open` class overrides a lot of CSS rules, so you'll need to provide a special rule, like:

```
.open > .dropdown-toggle {
  background: transparent;
}
```

You might also have to use the `!important` declaration too.

Comment: this works-ish. The background color is gone, but now on active, the text turns dark even when I have declared it as white.

Comment: Use the `!important` declaration for that too.